# PewDiePie Tuber Simulator Event

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

So I won a contest, and I won 94th in the Diamond section. But how do I get my prizes? Do they only appear after the 2 days?

Answer (score 1):

When you win an event you get your prizes by tapping a prize box that appears in a popup saying

> Congratulations! Your room was so popular in the last event that you won a prize!

The time it takes for this popup to appear after an event has ended varies. From my own experience it can take between 5 minutes up to 2 hours before it appears after the event ended.